# Inserting a list to mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

Hai, there, i got this huge list 5k in notepad delimited with new line, i want to insert this to a mysql table is there a way to do that, like a single query or like a antomated way to generate INSERT into bla bla bla..for all of them?

Answer (score 2):

Check the following link on how to import data into MySQL from a flat file: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysqlimport.html

There are also some fancy applications which can help you do this like [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/sqlyog_feature_matrix.php)